# Flutter won't return boolean in async await method

Tags: flutter, flutter-future, flutter-file

I need to check my file reading was successful and return true or false. I need to use async and await function because it needs to return true otherwise no point continuing.

I get a run time error from my snapshot: format.Exception:Invalid boolean false

Offending line is: bool result = await fb.readFile();

[image]

More detail image:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a working example? for example the definition of `fb` nor `Rung.myList` is not part of your example code. otherwise the code looks fine on a first glance.

Comment: I've added more detailed image of my code

Comment: try with FutureBuilder, & try to upload code-snippet instead of code-image. More about [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Comment: your IDE should mark this code as invalid, already before compiling: `bool result = await fb.readFile();` Reason being, that fb is not accesible in an initializer, since fb is initialized at the same time as result is (that being on creation of an A instance). also async code is prolly invalid as an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a return, maybe something like this:

```
Future<bool> boolFuture()async{
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
return false;
}
```

Good luck